# different DNS goes to different module of a JBoss application

Tags: apache, jboss, dns

We have a JBoss application that has 2 webapps. The flow is like

LB --> Apache --> JBoss

Now we have 2 DNS mapped to the same application, different webapp though.

privatedomain.com  should go to webapp1 @ path1/

publicdomain.com   should go to webapp2 @ path2/

I want to be sure that 

publicdomain.com/path1/

will not invoke my code in webapp1 as it should only be accessed by privatedomain.com.

Is it possible to achieve that restriction? If so, where and how to do it? Hope I explain it well. Thanks a lot for your helps/hints/clues in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Here is my Apache config

```
ServerAlias publicdomain.com

JKMount /path2/*  worker_myapp
```

```
ServerAlias privatedomain.com

JKMount /path1/*  worker_myapp
```

and if the URL is 
publicdomain.com/path1/...

Apache returns 404. And in the meanwhile,

publicdomain.com/path2/

privatedomain.com/path1/

work just fine